# F# Condition Statement

Tags: f#

How to write something

```
if !inBoundary then do 
 printfn "no it's not within the boundary"
```

Comment: `!` is used to dereference a `ref` in F#. e.g. if you have `let x = ref 1` you use it:- `let y = !x`; `not` is what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `not` [built-in function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370457.aspx) (and omit the `do` keyword after `then`):

```
let inBoundary = false

if not inBoundary then
    printfn "no it's not within the boundary"
```